# Since Laravel 5.3 update, my views are not refreshed properly when I update data in my DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

A really strange issue here. I had a Laravel 5.2 application which work perfectly. Then I update to Laravel 5.3 to use the new broadcasting features and I face a big issue.

When I update the data (with my application forms or directly in my database) the views are note updated properly. I try to clear cache, views and config but nothing change... I need to go to some others pages and the data finish by appear...

I have a `Campaign` model and a page which list campaigns. When I remove an entry directly in the database, the list doesn't change in front. Also when I use debugging functions like `dd` results tell me that data haven't changed...

Is there someone else which faced the same problem ?

I've followed the migration guide to update my 5.2 to 5.3, maybe I forgot something...

Here a piece of my `.env` file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Never store full model in session, it can lead to old data displayed in the application !

After a day of search and refactoring I found what was my original problem !

It's a simple `session()` statement which cause my application to display invalid data.

### History

The dashboard display a list of campaigns which are linked to a client. A user can manage multiple clients so I put the current client in session to know which one is currently used.

The mistake here is that I put the entire client model in session so when I read the session and retrieve data, all the relationships are retrieved too.

The client is the central point to access data in my application. I retrieve the campaigns linked to my client and everything is related to it.

Here the vicious function :

```
/**
 * Retrieve the current client instance when the user is connected
 * @return App\Client|null
 */
protected function retrieveCurrentClient()
{
    $client = null;

    if (Gate::allows('manage-clients')) {
        if (null === $client = session('currentClient')) {
            $client = Client::all()->first();
            session(['currentClient' => $client]);
        }
    } elseif (Auth::guard()->check()) {
        $client = Auth::guard()->user()->client;
    }

    return $client;
}
```

In fact the problem appeared when I dig around the Gate definition. If I remove them my application starts working again...

### Solution

I just change the function to store in session client id instead of the full Model. Then I retrieve fresh data in each page of my application.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the current client instance when the user is connected
 * @return App\Client|null
 */
protected function retrieveCurrentClient()
{
    $client = null;

    if (Gate::allows('manage-clients')) {
        if (null === $client_id = session('client_id')) {
            $client = Client::all()->first();
            session(['client_id' => $client->id]);
        } else {
            $client = Client::findOrFail($client_id);
        }
    } elseif (Auth::guard()->check()) {
        $client = Auth::guard()->user()->client;
    }

    return $client;
}
```

Don't know if it can help someone else to avoid that mistakes but happy to have found an answer !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing this questions.

Laravel successfully upgraded to version 5.3 and there are some deprecations and application service provider and also some new feature like passport are added.

Your problem is with view. As per my knowledge, you need to remove arguments from your "boot" method which are written in `EventServiceProvider`, `RouteServiceProvider`, `AuthServiceProvider` which are available on `app/provider/remove_the_arguments_from_boot_method_given_file`

In Laravel 5.2:

```
 public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        $this->registerPolicies($gate);
    }
```

But in Laravel 5.3:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

    }
```

Kindly refer [Laravel 5.3 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)

I hope, this works for you.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've checked all the update between 5.2 and 5.3 and follows all the instructions. I found my answer today, my problem was related to my session usage...

Comment: I've posted the solution in a new answer, will be accepted asap